# Total number of 8 digit numbers divisible by 3 and composed of 4, 5 and 6?

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the total possible 8 digit numbers made using 4, 5 and 6 is $3^8$. But if one more constraint is added like the number must be divisible by 3, how do we find it. The answer is $3^7$, but I cannot explain it. I am having hard time with counting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By symmetry, $\frac{1}{3}$ of the numbers would be divisible by $3$, so $3^8 \cdot \frac{1}{3}=3^7$.

Comment: Can you give a generalized approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *any* integer $a$, exactly one of $a+4$, $a+5$, and $a+6$ will be divisible by 3.

Thus, whenever you have chosen the first 7 digits, exactly one of the choices for the last digit will result in a number that's divisible by 3.

Comment: Excellent, I have no words for this.

Answer (score 1):

We prove by induction that $\frac{1}{3}$ of the $n$-digit numbers have remainder $0$ on division by $3$, $\frac{1}{3}$ have remainder $1$, and $\frac{1}{3}$ have remainder $2$.  It is useful to use the language of probabilities: we prove that a randomly selected number of length $n$ has probability $\frac{1}{3}$ of having remainder $0$, of having remainder $1$, and of having remainder $2$.

Suppose the result is correct when $n=k$. We show the result is true for $n=k+1$.
Recall that the remainder of a number on division by $3$ is the remainder when the sum of its digits is divided by $3$.

Take a $(k+1)$-digit number. It is equally likely to end in $4$, $5$, or $6$. If it ends in $4$, then it has remainder $0$ precisely if the number obtained by deleting the $4$ has remainder $2$. The probability of this is, by the induction hypothesis, $\frac{1}{3}$. A similar calculation shows the probability is also $\frac{1}{3}$ if the last digit is $5$, and if the last digit is $6$.

Similar calculations show that the same is true for remainder $1$ and for remainder $2$.